# Generic vs Overloading in terms of execution speed

Tags: c++, generics, overloading

I am trying to find how the execution speed defers while using generic programming concept over overloading.
Here is my code.

## overloading

```
class Addition{
public:
    int sum (int a, int b){
        return a+b;
    }

    double sum (double a, double b){
        return a+b;
    }
};

int main(){
    Addition a;
    cout<<a.sum(5,6)<<endl;
    cout<<a.sum(5.1,6.2)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

## Generic

```
template <class T>
class Addition{
public:
    T sum(T a,T b){
        return a+b;
    }
};

int main(){
    Addition <int>a;
    Addition <double>b;
    cout<<a.sum(5,6)<<endl;
    cout<<b.sum(5.1,6.2);
    return 0;
}
```

I found that generic concept is more efficient but I want to know why?
Update: Generic was seen more efficient because of missing endl as mentioned by @user15388024

Comment: what made you conclude that one is more efficient than the other?

Comment: claims about efficiency need much more to be meaningful. What compiler, what compiler settings, how did you measure, on what machine? Without that information, saying "A is more efficient than B" has little meaning

Comment: Any choice in this code as regards functions on `int` vs on `double` is done at compile time. I think there's no runtime difference. Measure it if you think there is.

Comment: I benchmarked your code with https://quick-bench.com/q/OdgFIOROlvUVzajZkaa5hemVupQ The difference is the missing `<<endl` in your second code. After I added it the benchmarks are equal: https://quick-bench.com/q/vCxh4G8acvEAR2IWisU-gFbZdE0 Replacing `endl` with `'\n'` increases the performance a little bit: https://quick-bench.com/q/GsNKlf5k2ZK3r8n6RHy68USWvdg

Comment: The compiler will use your templates classes to generate class instantiations for each template type used, so there'll never be performance differences in scenarios like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I benchmarked your code with https://quick-bench.com/q/OdgFIOROlvUVzajZkaa5hemVupQ

```
#include <iostream>
class Addition1{
public:
    int sum (int a, int b){
        return a+b;
    }

    double sum (double a, double b){
        return a+b;
    }
};

template <class T>
class Addition2{
public:
    T sum(T a,T b){
        return a+b;
    }
};

static void Overloading(benchmark::State& state) {
  // Code inside this loop is measured repeatedly
  for (auto _ : state) {
    Addition1 a;
    std::cout<<a.sum(5,6)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<a.sum(5.1,6.2)<<std::endl;

    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(a);
  }
}
// Register the function as a benchmark
BENCHMARK(Overloading);

static void Generic(benchmark::State& state) {
  // Code before the loop is not measured
  for (auto _ : state) {
    Addition2 <int>a;
    Addition2 <double>b;
    std::cout<<a.sum(5,6)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<b.sum(5.1,6.2);

    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(a);
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(b);
  }
}
BENCHMARK(Generic);
```

[image]
The difference is the missing `<<endl` in your second code.

After I added it the benchmarks are equal: https://quick-bench.com/q/vCxh4G8acvEAR2IWisU-gFbZdE0

```
#include <iostream>
class Addition1{
public:
    int sum (int a, int b){
        return a+b;
    }

    double sum (double a, double b){
        return a+b;
    }
};

template <class T>
class Addition2{
public:
    T sum(T a,T b){
        return a+b;
    }
};

static void Overloading(benchmark::State& state) {
  // Code inside this loop is measured repeatedly
  for (auto _ : state) {
    Addition1 a;
    std::cout<<a.sum(5,6)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<a.sum(5.1,6.2)<<std::endl;

    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(a);
  }
}
// Register the function as a benchmark
BENCHMARK(Overloading);

static void Generic(benchmark::State& state) {
  // Code before the loop is not measured
  for (auto _ : state) {
    Addition2 <int>a;
    Addition2 <double>b;
    std::cout<<a.sum(5,6)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<b.sum(5.1,6.2)<<std::endl;

    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(a);
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(b);
  }
}
BENCHMARK(Generic);
```

[image]

Replacing `endl` with `'\n'` increases the performance a little bit:
https://quick-bench.com/q/GsNKlf5k2ZK3r8n6RHy68USWvdg

```
#include <iostream>
class Addition1{
public:
    int sum (int a, int b){
        return a+b;
    }

    double sum (double a, double b){
        return a+b;
    }
};

template <class T>
class Addition2{
public:
    T sum(T a,T b){
        return a+b;
    }
};

static void Overloading(benchmark::State& state) {
  // Code inside this loop is measured repeatedly
  for (auto _ : state) {
    Addition1 a;
    std::cout<<a.sum(5,6)<<'\n';
    std::cout<<a.sum(5.1,6.2)<<'\n';

    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(a);
  }
}
// Register the function as a benchmark
BENCHMARK(Overloading);

static void OverloadingEndl(benchmark::State& state) {
  // Code inside this loop is measured repeatedly
  for (auto _ : state) {
    Addition1 a;
    std::cout<<a.sum(5,6)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<a.sum(5.1,6.2)<<std::endl;

    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(a);
  }
}
// Register the function as a benchmark
BENCHMARK(OverloadingEndl);
```

[image]